# Basic partitioning settings and advice when installing Ubuntu and Windows 7 on a wiped laptop

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I'm trying to wipe my laptop and install both Ubuntu and Windows 7 on it.

I am doing the installation now, but I am unsure about a few settings relating to the partitioning.

- What type should I use for the new partition? Should I use "primary" for Ubuntu and "logical" for Windows?
- What should be the location for the new partition?
- What should I choose in the "Use as" dropdown menu where I have: Ext4 journaling file system, Fat32 and so on?
- Should the mount point be /boot for Ubuntu?

I do not know which settings would be optimal for Windows and which for Linux, and I prefer asking directly instead of just taking some of the answers on Google for a not completely similar problem.

Additionally, are there any settings I have to be aware of during the installation to make sure we can choose to boot from Linux or Windows every time we boot?

Comment: Probably better to read a few threads here first so you don't leap in without knowing what you are doing. There's plenty to choose from, just search or look at the side bar on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its simple , first install Windows on Primary Partition  C Drive and then use any partitioning software to delete any of the partition in which you want to install Ubuntu or use Windows Disk Management to delete that partition .Preferably choose the last partition of your disk  having at least 20gigs.

Create Bootable USB Stick y using Universal Universal Installer , as explained [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) or create a bootable Dvd as Shown [here.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows)

Then restart your system and enter into Bios and change the boot Priorities to either USB or Dvd, depending on what you are using to install it.

After Saving changes restart your pc and connect USB then Ubuntu Installation Interface will be prompted , in that choose INSTALL UBUNTU , provide all the details , When it ask for where to install choose **Something Else** , here you have to be very careful , do exactly what I am about to say -

Look at the partion , there will be one named as **FREE SPACE** click on that then click on **+** to split it into usable partition  , then change the size of the partition by scroll down option or enter it manually ,the size should exactly same as the Physicall ram or Double of it and in the format option choose **SWAP AREA** let it be logical and check at the end of SPACE.  till now we are done with creating swap partion.

Next click on **+** again and let the size as it is then check begining of the space and choose partion **EXT4** and in the mount Option choose **/** that is for root partition means everything will be installed in it, and let this to be **LOGICAL**.

Click next and Install it .

Remember both the partitions are **LOGICAL** , swap is at the end of space and root at the beginning ,in swap just select format as SWAP AREA with no mount option and for root Partition choose the partition EXT4 with mount point / .

Hope i have explained exactly what you want.

Comment: This makes sense. At the bottom, what do I set as "Device for boot loader installation?"

I have 
-sda1 Windows 7 (loader) 25 mb
-sda6 ext4 / unknown 314 gb
-sda5 swap 32 mb
-sda3 with the actual Windows installation 185 gb

I'm asuming /dev/sda6?

Comment: I also have the option /dev/sda, which is my entire hard drive.

Comment: dev/sda is by default let it be,remember it will use Grub (Ubuntu's boot loader) to load all systems on this hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is: first install Windows on the whole disc. after you finished that install Ubuntu and choose the 'install alongside Windows' option in the installation menu. this should take care of everything automatically.

But you can also choose to partition the disc manually, which gives you more controll but makes it a bit more complicated.

It remains that you best first install Windows, In its installer you already leave some space free for your Ubuntu installation.

now you install Ubuntu, In the "use as" drop-down you choose EXT4. and as mount point you choose "/".

Now when you manually partition I would advise to make a separate partition for "/home". this is where all your documents and application settings are stored. that means that when you reinstall Ubuntu the next time none of that should get lost (although always backup!). in this setup you make a relative small partition (for example 20 gb if you have the space) for your Ubuntu and applications and mount it as "/" and the rest of your disc a partition mounted as "/home" for your documents.

edit: I forgot about the swap partition, in both cases where you do the partition manually you have to make a small partition (max twice the RAM in your system) and select under "use as" Swap!

Answer (score 0):

*..."primary" for Ubuntu and "logical" for Windows?* **Nope!** Windows OS *should* be installed to a *primary* partition; for Ubuntu you can use either *primary* or *logical*.

For an [Ubuntu installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/i386/howto-installation.html) you'll need at least one partition (ext4/ext3/ext2) for the ***root ( / ) partition*** ([at least 5GB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace)). A ***[swap partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq)*** of size equal to (or up to 3 times if you're short on RAM) the size of your RAM is recommended. Although newer systems have a good deal of RAM available, a *swap* is still recommended if you use sleep or hibernation features. These two are the recommended partitions. (If you like, you can create separate partitions for /home, /boot, ... You can have them all in the logical partitions.

Here is the layout of my partitions.
[image]
In my hard disk ***sda***, sda1, used for Windows and sda2, for Ubuntu's **root ( / ) partition**  are primary (but you can use a logical partition for **/** ). A swap partition of size equal to 1.5x RAM in logical partition.

If you're not very comfortable partitioning on yourself, you could allow Ubuntu installation disk do it for by choosing *install alongside Windows option*.